# Problem in a function actionscript

Tags: function, actionscript-2

How do I add a variable that varies with the dummy variable in a loop:

```
function resetAll(menuNum){
  trace(menuNum);
  for (i=0; i<=7; i++){
    if(menuNum != 1){
      menu_all_mc.this["btn_"+i].gotoAndStop("off");
    }
  }
}
```

this["btn_"+i] don`t work

I need pass the btn name like: btn_1 and next loop btn_2 ...

Comment: FYI: saying "this doesnt work", without providing an "expected result" is not helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm strictly guessing ( I don't do Actionscript but JS ), but if your `i` variable stays the same then you'll need to use closures to capture and bind that `i` in place:

```
function resetAll(menuNum){
    trace(menuNum);
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++){
    (function(i){
        if(menuNum != 1){
            menu_all_mc.this["btn_"+i].gotoAndStop("off"); 
        }
    })(i);
    }
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work. Also make sure the `this` keyword is referencing the correct execution context.

Edit: the `this` can't be referenced like that, are you sure it's not just `menu_all_mc["btn_" +i]` ? `this` isn't a property of an object unless you explicitly define it as such.

```
o = {};
trace( o.this==undefined )
```

would evaluate to true because it was never defined. `this` in a function scope will refer to the current execution context but do not prefix it with another object.

Can you clarify what object owns the .btn1, etc?

Comment: Speculation in a language you don't know isn't extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu_all_mc.this["btn_"+i].gotoAndStop("off");
```

`this` cannot be a member of a class, I am guessing you want

```
menu_all_mc["btn_"+i].gotoAndStop("off");
```

Or even

```
menu_all_mc[this["btn_"+i]]gotoAndStop("off");
```